# Dealing with files when file system is set to private download

Tags: 6, media, files

I am working on a site where the file system security is a bit important. So we have it configured to use a private directory with the private download method is enabled. And this works great for the most part.

However, the [Avatar Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatarcrop) module is having a problem. Specifically during the cropping process it is trying to send the system path on the server to the image "src" parameter and not a path that will display it through the private download method. Another person reported this bug, but the maintainers just ignored it. So now I have this problem too and I am trying to fix the module (and submit the fix to the community).

To fix it I am exploring other modules like [ImageCache](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache) and the [CCK filefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield) module. So far I am not having much luck in recognizing how to work with this private download method. Can anyone explain how the file is supposed to be retrieved through the private download method?